# How do I get the text from UITextField into an NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextfield

I've tried various methods, which all give me warnings. Such as `userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [yournamefield stringValue]];` which just gives me a warning of

> 'UITextField' may not respond to '-stringValue'

How do i do this?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888

Comment: `-stringValue` is a method of `NSTextField`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Get the text inside the text field using the `text` property

```
NSString *name = yourNameField.text;
```

Comment: No! Do **not** use the accessor method for something that is explicitly defined as a property in the public header.

Comment: @PeyloW Can I quickly ask why this is not to be done? Isn't that what a property s doing, generating accessors? Won't the runtime convert the dot syntax to the accessor syntax?

Comment: @MattM: Yes it is what the implementation is doing, but you should only think of that as an implementation detail and a side effect of backwards compatibility to Objective-C 1.0. Properties are intended for **state**, and methods are for **behavior**. Accessing a property as a method compiles, but your code clearly tells that you misunderstand the APIs intention.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't agree with you here.  Apple's own docs say that the dot syntax is syntactic sugar provided as an alternative to square bracket notation. Admittedly it does have the advantage of the compiler signalling an error when it detects an attempt to write to a read-only declared property, whereas square brackets at best generate an undeclared method warning.  However, it certainly does not imply a misunderstanding of the APIs intention.

Comment: @PeyloW Please, look at `NSDateComponents` and tell me if has state or behavior. Your argument is wrong. _Property_ is term not strictly related to `@property` syntax. Even in Objective-C 1.0 you used _properties_, but you had to to write accessors yourself. Dot syntax is just easier way to invoke methods without arguments, but should not be abused for clearly behavioral methods. But this is just styling issue and it _works exactly the same_. It's not implementation detail. --- Ah, again an old question, that appeared on SO main page :(

Answer (score 11):

Use the `text` property of `UITextField`:

```
NSString *userName = yourNameField.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yournamefield.text];
```

Comment: Why use `stringWithFormat:` if the string the only content of the format string?

Comment: No reason - it was a quick change from his original post :).

Answer (score 1):

Two ways. 
It is a property and any property value can be accessed like this -

- `yournamefield.text`
- `[yournamefield text]`