# Accessing text in a text field

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm a student using Xcode 6 and what I need to know is how the user can type input and then I can use that input in a formula. For instance:
The user inputs 5 in one field, 7 in another and 9 and a third and then I use these three numbers in a math formula to return a value. The formula could be something like: 9/7/5 = 0.25

I'm new to programming with Swift, and I have been searching the web for an answer and I somehow can't find what I'm looking for although it's a relatively simple concept. Code examples are definitely preferred and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help others answer your question, please provide some code showing what you've tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: how far have you gotten so far?

Comment: Start by learning about `UITextField`s. You can use their `text` property to get the input. Then it's a matter of parsing from a string to an int or float or whatever your formula requires.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the text from UITextField into an NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660200/how-do-i-get-the-text-from-uitextfield-into-an-nsstring)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27866767/2303865

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. All you need to do is get the input values using the `text` property of `UITextField` like `textField1.text`

For more info refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField